# Avoid to insert additional text asking the user how to proceed in terminal

Tags: powershell

I have some filenames like

```
gigi il bullo.avi
highlander.avi
Highlander 2 1080p.mkv
Gloria una notte d'estate.rar
```

In same folder I have a text file *.txt* with this text

```
Gigi (1958)
Highlander (1986)
Highlander 2 - Il ritorno (1990)
Gloria (2013)
```

then script do 4 wrong things:

1. it renames `gigi il bullo` into `Gigi (1986)`
2. it doesn't rename `highlander.avi` into `Highlander (1986)`
3. it renames `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` into `Highlander (1986)`
4. it renames `Gloria una notte d'estate.rar` into `Gloria (2013)`

I would to avoid to insert additional text into text file to rename correctly. In practice, the addition text that I should add into movielist.txt should be this

```
Gigi il bullo (1968)
Highlander 2 (1990)
Gloria una notte d'estate (1980)
...
...
Gigi (1958)
Highlander (1986)
Highlander 2 - Il ritorno (1990)
```

It should correctly rename like this

```
gigi il bullo.avi
Highlander (1986).avi
Highlander 2 - Il ritorno (1990).mkv
Gloria una notte d'estate.rar
```

but I think that is not possible so I also thought of another thing: if there are ambiguous situations then the script should not rename but at least show ambiguous names asking the user how to proceed, for example showing something like this

```
There are 2 ambiguous filenames

highlander.avi
Highlander 2 1080p.mkv

Would you rename Highlander 2 1080p.mkv into Highlander (1986) ? [Y=yes, N=no]
```

I use this script

```
$titles = Get-Content -Path 'Z:\FILM\movielist.txt' -Encoding UTF8 | Select-Object -Unique
# first create a Hashtable with searchable (cleaned-up) titles and the actual title you want as filename
$titleMap = @{}
foreach ($title in $titles) {
    
    # remove everything after a square bracket, remove the year in between brackets, 
    # remove all non-ascii characters and trim trailing spaces
    $search = ($title -replace '(\(\d{4}\)|\[.*|\s*)$' -replace '[^\x00-\x7F]+' -replace '\.|\s+', ' ').Trim()
    $titleMap[$search] = $title
}

# next, get an array of these search titels, sorted on Length reversed
# to avoid bad renames on ambiguous names like 'Il cavaliere oscuro' and 'Il cavaliere oscuro - Il ritorno'
$searchTitles = $titleMap.Keys | Sort-Object Length -Descending


# get the list of files in the foler
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'Z:\FILM\' -File -Exclude 'movielist.txt'
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $search = ($file.BaseName -replace '(\(\d{4}\)|\[.*|\s*)$' -replace '[^\x00-\x7F]+' -replace '\.|\s+', ' ').Trim()
    # extend each object with a cleaned-up searchable name
    $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'SearchName' -Value $search
}

# now loop through the search titles and try to find matching filenames from the files
foreach ($title in $searchTitles) {
    $files | Where-Object { $_.SearchName -like "*$title*" } | ForEach-Object {
        # use '-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue' to avoid errors on files that have already been renamed
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $titleMap[$title], $_.Extension) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

Comment: One of those issues can be fixed by sorting the length of the name. Just a lot of ambiguity in those files to distinguish it from one another.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala My problem is to avoid adding the missing text, so I was looking for this workaround. For example, if my filename is `gigi il bullo` and I only have `gigi` in the text file, then the script has to stop and ask me the question, so I can press `Yes / No` to avoid renaming it to the wrong name. it's possible?

Comment: Do you have a threshold for when it should ask you? You could try to match all words (excluding year) in the titles of your text file, and then if it doesn't match all words ask you.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, if I have as file name "gigi il bullo.avi" but this name is not present in the text file, but instead only "Gigi (1980)" is present but "gigi il bullo (1970)" is not present in text file , then you should ask me. Or if in the text file I have only "gigi il bullo" but in my folder I only have a file called "gigi.mkv" then it must ask me. Another example, if I have the file name "the war.avi" and "the war in malaysia.mkv" but have both names in the text file, for example "the war (1980)" and "the war in malaysia (1990) " then those files will already be renamed correctly

Comment: and you don't need to ask .  The problem is only when the file name is not present in the text file (or vice versa) or if there is only a part of that name in the text file, not when the entire file name is present in full both in the file text and both in the file name

Answer (score 0):

That is because your text file misses a few titles.

- Add `Highlander 2 (1990)` to the text file
- Add `Gloria una notte d'estate (year)` to the text file
- Add `gigi il bullo (year)` to the text file

The longer titles get compared **first**. If there is only a short version in the text file that matches, that will be used instead.
That is why for instance `gigi il bullo` matches just `Gigi` because there isn't a more appropriate choice.

The file `highlander.avi` doesn't get renamed, because `Highlander 2 1080p.mkv` was already renamed to `Highlander (1986)` and that would be a naming collision.
(-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` then simply skips the action and proceeds with the next file.)

Comment: ok, I have `Gloria una notte d'estate.rar` but in text file only `Gloria (2013)`. These names sharing same `gloria` word: it is possible to make the terminal stop temporarily and instead of renaming immediately, it asks me to rename and if I choose `Yes` then only afterwards can it proceed. My problem is to avoid adding the missing text, so I was looking for this workaround. For example, if my filename is `gigi il bullo` and I only have `gigi` in the text file, then the script has to stop and ask me the question, so I can press `Yes / No` to avoid renaming it to the wrong name. it's possible?

Comment: More than a matching problem to rename I would like a previous condition that avoids me a wrong renaming action, so the matching is used to invoke a question from the terminal so that I decide what to do.